# MVC 4 Bundles Scripts.Render script tag for each file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, bundle

Is there any way to force the bundles in MVC 4 to render a script tag for each of the bundled files for development purposes?

Answer (score 4):

In the development/debug environment (where the compilation Element in the Web.config file is set to `debug="true"`) the JavaScript files are not bundled or minified.
You don't use a  tag in JavaScript files, it's used in obtrusive JavaScript embedded in you HTML. What are you trying to do? See my [Bundling and Minification tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification)